# Using this within functions called with onclick event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, dom, this

I'm currently building a small Todo list application using vanilla Javascript but I'm having some issues creating a delete button that onClick removes it's parent element.

From what I have read, when an onClick is called in Javascript the this keyword can be used to refer to the element that called the function. With this in mind I have the following code:

```
window.onload = initialiseTodo;

function addRecord(){
  var title = document.getElementById('issueTitle');
  var issueContent = document.getElementById('issueContent');
  var contentArea = document.getElementById('contentArea');

  if(title.value.length > 0 && issueContent.value.length > 0){
   var newItem = document.createElement('div');
   newItem.id = 'task' + count++;
   newItem.className = 'task';
   newItem.innerHTML = '<div class="taskbody"><h1>' + title.value + '</h1>'+ issueContent.value + '</div><div class="deleteContainer">'
   + '<a class="delete">DELETE</a></div>';
   contentArea.appendChild(newItem);
   assignDeleteOnclick();
  }
}

function deleteRecord(){
   this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);
}

function assignDeleteOnclick(){
  var deleteArray = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');
    for(var i=0;i<deleteArray.length;i++){
      deleteArray[i].onclick= deleteRecord();
    }
}

function initialiseTodo(){
 var btn_addRecord = document.getElementById('addRecord');
 btn_addRecord.onclick = addRecord;
}
```

Basically I have a form that has two fields. When these fields are filled and the addRecord button is clicked a new div is added at the bottom of the page. This div contains a delete button. After the creation of this I assign an onclick event to the delete button which assigns the deleteRecord function when the delete button is clicked. My issue is with the deleteRecord function. I have used this to refer to the calling element (the delete button) and wish to remove the task div that is the outermost container however I current get a message that says: 'Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined ' which suggests to me the this keyword is not working correctly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've added the full code to a fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/Bd8AR/

J

Comment: Here's the reason, your code is: deleteArray[i].onclick= deleteRecord();
which means the onclick property is assigned the return value of deleteRecord(), you should change it to deleteArray[i].onclick= deleteRecord; Besides, there're two many parentNode in your delete function, change it to this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); And here's the result: http://jsfiddle.net/Bd8AR/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the element itself as a parameter. I did so by changing the html to include `onclick="deleteRecord(this)"` to make it a little easier to deal with. This means you can remove the `assignDeleteOnclick()` function

```
function deleteRecord(elem){
  elem.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Bd8AR/1/)

You might style the `.content` to be hidden better if there are no elements to prevent that extra white space

**Edit**

Since you don't want an inline `onclick`, you can do it with js the same:

```
function deleteRecord(elem){
  elem.parentNode.parentNode.remove();
}
function assignDeleteOnclick(){
  var deleteArray = document.getElementsByClassName('delete');
    for(var i=0;i<deleteArray.length;i++){

        // Has to be enveloped in a function() { } or else context is lost
        deleteArray[i].onclick=function() { deleteRecord(this); }     
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/Bd8AR/2/)

Comment: I don't want to declare the onclick inline as that is bad practise. How can this be achieved programmatically?

Comment: @jezzipin Updated based on the clarification

Comment: Great thanks. I usually use jQuery so this is a lot easier but thought it was about time I brushed up on my core js skills

Comment: @jezzipin I'm all for low resources, high performing pure js code!