# why keyword 'this' doesn't work, in html and js?

Tags: javascript, this

http://jsfiddle.net/#run&togetherjs=2c9lcPPkKn

source is right on there.

and my question is,

html : `onClick="this.blahblahblah='blah'"` <- this code works, but

```
function test() { this.blahblah='blah'; }
```

html : `onClick="test()"` <- this doesn't work.

why is that? why the keyword 'this' doesn't work?

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not in a fiddle.

Comment: The reason is because `this.*` in `onClick` would be referring to the element with the attribute onClick, while `this.*` within the function doesn't have any this context set. You can achieve the same result with, `onClick="test.call(this)"`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using this within functions called with onclick event in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894118/using-this-within-functions-called-with-onclick-event-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with how javascript calls a function when you put a function call in quotes for the onclick handler.  Because you're just supply a string which the browser has to figure out how to parse to javascript and run, the browser uses a form of `eval()` to process the string.  `eval()` takes the string, finds a function call `test()` and processes that.

Any normal function call in javascript resets the `this` pointer to be either the global object or `undefined` in strict mode.  Thus you lose the `this` pointer when you do `onclick="test()"`.

If you want the `this` pointer preserved, you can either pass it manually as already shown in one of the other answers with:

```
onclick="test(this)"
```

and then use the first argument of your function as the object reference.

---

Or, you can add an event listener and then the `this` pointer will be automatically set appropriately for you.

```
 <div id="test"></div>

 document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
     // the this pointer will be set to the test object here
     this.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
 });
```

---

I don't recommend this because using unobtrusive javascript techniques where you get your javascript out of your HTML and use event listeners is a better approach, but you could do this to get the `this` pointer set appropriately:

```
onclick="test.call(this)"
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4Qsj2/

Comment: than, there is no way to make 'this' keyword reffers <div> instead 'onClick'?

Comment: @baejusik - if you really wanted, you could do this:  `onclick="test.call(this)">`, but why not just use unobstrusive javascript techniques and get your javascript out of your HTML and use event listeners which is a better architectural and structural choice?

Answer (score 3):

That's different context.

```
onClick="test(this)"

function test(cmp) { cmp.blahblah='blah'; }
```

In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of. When we define our faithful function doSomething() in a page, its owner is the page, or rather, the window object (or global object) of JavaScript. An onclick property, though, is owned by the HTML element it belongs to.

Comment: Than how can use 'this' keyword in function? As you know, find objects using getElements.. one by one is inconveniente. I'd like to use 'this' keyword, and make it conveniently...

Comment: It's very easy. In JavaScript this always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of. When we define our faithful function doSomething() in a page, its owner is the page, or rather, the window object (or global object) of JavaScript. An onclick property, though, is owned by the HTML element it belongs to.

Comment: var me = this; good practice in javascript for saving context reference;

Comment: This "owner" concept is misleading. Who's the owner of the following `f` call? `f=instance.method;f()`. Just think of `this` as one more implicit argument, whose value depends on **how** you call the function.

Comment: So you mean, in that source.. 'this' keyword reffers 'onClick'? than How can make 'this' keywords reffers <div> instead of 'onClick'? the code is : <div onClick="test()"></div>

Comment: read this link for better understanding of 'this' keyword in js.

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html

Comment: @Igor That's a good comment and should be part of your answer, which is otherwise very brief and doesn't really explain what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `this` is JavaScript depends sooo much on context. If you're familiar with `this` from many languages, like Java or C#, forget what you know. If you are not, that's fine.

**JavaScript `this` Meanings**

In the following examples, unless I denote otherwise, each snippet is inside the global scope. That means not wrapped in a function.

*Global Object*

```
console.log(this);
```

In this snippet, `this` refers to the JavaScript global object. Shove this code in a `.js` and run it through a browser. You'll see a result in the console something like this:

```
[Window sojs25113015.html]
```

**Most of the time, this is not what you want.** Note that `this` refers to the global object, even inside a function - if the function is declared inside the global scope, and called from the context of the global object. (More on context in a moment.)

```
function logEcho() {
  console.log(this);
}

var logEcho2 = function() {
  console.log(this);
}
```

In either one of these, called just like `logEcho()` or `logEcho2()` would also log the global object.

*With a different context (or "owner")*

Say we have a button:

```
<button onclick="logEcho()"></button>
```

And we click on it. In the browser console, you will again see that the global object is logged. What's wrong here? Nothing - `logEcho()` is called in context of the global object. This may seem odd, especially if you're familiar with libraries such as jQuery. As an example in jQuery, a similar function could look like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery("button").click(function() {
    console.log(this);
  });
});
```

And the result of the `console.log()` call?

```
<button>
```

Exactly what we would expect.

*How is this possible?*

Doing away with jQuery now, we can do something similar, by modifying the context of the call to `logEcho()`. The new button:

```
<button onclick="logEcho.apply(this)"></button>
```

and the result of clicking on it in the console:

```
<button onclick="logEcho.apply(this)">
```

Exactly what we might expect. This is just one way that you can change the function's context in JavaScript.

*Object context, i.e. what you're used to from Java or C#*

Take the following JavaScript,

```
var person = function(first, last) {
  return {
    firstName: first,
    lastName: last,
    fullName: function() {
      return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName; 
    }
  }
}

var bob = person("Bob", "Smith");
console.log(bob.fullName());
```

This will output `Bob Smith`. The reason is because `fullName` is called in the context of a `person`, in this case `bob`.

I hope this information is useful to you.

Comment: Also hunted [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) down, it explains with different examples some of what I posted, and a few more that I didn't.

Answer (score -2):

Try below code:

```
<h1 onClick=this.style.backgroundColor='black> asdfasdfafd </h1>
<div  id="test"> 123123123 </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#test").click(function(c{
        this.style.backgroundColor=black;
    });t)
  k;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
onClick="test(this)";
```

This will pass the object to the called function and then you can do operations on that object.

Comment: Your code snippet is correct. Please add some explanation to increase the understanding of other programmers.